# GameObject won't change after updating it with a Method (object reference not set)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Unity newb here :)

I have a button which calls this function which basicly sets a prefab to instantiate.

```
  public void setTurret()
{
    towerNode.setTurretType(turret)
    Debug.Log("selected shop turret:" + turret.name);
}
```

My `Tower_Node` class handles the actual instantiate

```
 public class Tower_Node : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private GameObject turret;

               public void setTurretType(TowerType _turret) 
                   {
                        turret= _turret.prefab;
                    }



               private void OnMouseDown()
               {             
                Instantiate(turret,GetBuildPosition(),Quaternion.identity);
               }
    ...}
```

***EDIT:*** What I also tried

```
      public class Tower_Node : MonoBehaviour
        {
            private TowerType turret;

                   public void setTurretType(TowerType _turret) 
                       {
                            turret = _turret;
                    }



               private void OnMouseDown()
               {             
                Instantiate(turret.prefab,GetBuildPosition(),Quaternion.identity);
               }
    ...}
```

**EDIT:**
[This is how the references in the inspector look. The shop script is the script with the setTurret() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwtC9.png)

--

Setting the turret with the `setTurretType` method works. If i check it with Debug.Log() i get the right TowerType but outside of the function the gameobject is still `=null` and when i try to instantiate it gives me an ***NullReferenceException*** (because Gameobject is null obviously)

What am i missing here?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple instances of `Tower_Node` but you do not use `setTurretType` on all of them?

Comment: My `Tower_Node` is a prefab, which exists multiple times in my scene. `setTurretType` should update all of them since its a prefab right?

Answer (score 0):

switch OnMouseDown() for

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

in your update loop

just make sure that turret.prefab is a prefab

```
Instantiate(turret.prefab, GetBuildPosition(),Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: This did not work, and yes im sure that the prefab is a prefab!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if your TowerType class has a GameObject var named prefab, you should either assign the prefab to the prefab, or assign the turret to the _turret and the access the prefab.

Either this:

```java
public void setTurretType(TowerType _turret) {
    turret = _turret;
    hoverTurret = _turret.hoverPrefab;  
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Instantiate(turret.prefab, GetBuildPosition(),Quaternion.identity);
}
```

or

```java
public void setTurretType(TowerType _turret) {
    turret.prefab = _turret.prefab;
    hoverTurret = _turret.hoverPrefab;  
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Instantiate(turret.prefab, GetBuildPosition(),Quaternion.identity);
}
```

should work.

**Edit:**
You could set the turret while instiantiating:

```java
public void setTurretType(TowerType _turret) {
    turret.prefab = _turret.prefab;
    hoverTurret = _turret.hoverPrefab;  
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    turret = Instantiate(turret.prefab, GetBuildPosition(),Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Yes my TowerType class have a `public GameObject prefab`.
I tried both, but unfortunaly this did not work, the object still won't update

Comment: Are you setting the prefab to null somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, im not thats the only piece of code which modifies that

Comment: Sadly this also did not work, even when i set the var to [SerializeField] this does not work, but i can see in the inspector how the actual prefab is swapped. I really dont get why its null

Comment: Then I would say you need to provide more information with your other classes...